# Stored procedure return empty

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have an encrypted stored procedure in SQL Server so I can't modify it.
When I run it through SQL Server Management Studio I can get the result, but when I call it from codeigniter the result is empty.
Then I tried to create a new stored procedure and call it from codeigniter,it works fine. Is the problem because it's encrypted or something else?? how to fix it without having to modify the stored procedure because I don't have access to it.

```
public function getData(){
    $this->db2 = $this->load->database('mssql', TRUE);
    $result = $this->db2->query(exec RptLRA_Gabungan @Tahun='2022', @Kd_Urusan='', @Kd_Bidang = '', @Kd_Unit = '', @Kd_Sub = '', @Kd_Prog = '', @Id_Prog = '', @Kd_Keg = '', @level='3',  @D1 = '20220101', @D2 = '20221231');

    if(!$result){
        return $this->db2->last_query();
    }else{
        return $result->result_array();
    }
}
```

The result is just an empty array.

Comment: have you add double quote in `$this->db2->query`? like this `$result = $this->db2->query("exec RptLRA_Gabungan @Tahun='2022', @Kd_Urusan='', @Kd_Bidang = '', @Kd_Unit = '', @Kd_Sub = '', @Kd_Prog = '', @Id_Prog = '', @Kd_Keg = '', @level='3',  @D1 = '20220101', @D2 = '20221231'");`